# WCF ClientCredentials

Tags: wcf, authentication, window

please help. Half of the kingdom for a correct answer!!!
Is it possible to use WCF Windows authentication with the anonymous access option? My WCF service deployed in the AD domain, and there are some clients outside of the  domain. Can I use windows authentication to get client credentials for users that are in the AD and the same time allow access to the users they are not in the domain?  Thanks.
P.S. Sorry for poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to create a service configuration that exposes two different endpoints. One endpoint would use your current config. The new endpoint would be for the non-AD clients and you would configure it [using the options listed here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx) For anonymous access, you could pick [an unsecured client configuration.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733091.aspx) If your service host is IIS, you may need to have two different sites/applications because I believe enabling Windows authentication will disable anonymous access.